# Add HTML elements after Social Share Buttons

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a working shortcode after Single Product Social share buttons. I Have a page builder plugin which add custom made content with a shortcode anywhere in wordpress post/page.How can I add that shortcode after social share buttons in single product page in woocommerce. like [this](https://ibb.co/chLfE7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use following hooked function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'after_woocommerce_share', 100 );
function after_woocommerce_share(){
    // Your code
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: if I just use the wordpress shortcode [mycode] inside the function, will it work ?

Comment: @Tanvir Yes, using `echo do_shortcode("[mycode]");`…

Comment: thnk u very much